# How to remotely close/kill application on ms windows

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, remote-login

I wonder is it possible to turn off/kill/close an application on ms windows xp. On linux machine I've alway login by ssh and the use shell command. How it works on windows? Is there any ssh build in serwer?

I would like to not use gui. I prefer shell/cmd.

Comment: You can use PSKill: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pskill.aspx

Comment: If I am a domain admin I can kill apps on computer in domain When I have higher permissions?

Comment: Windows, (until server2016 is released) does not support SSH natively. Most people use the SysInternals Suite's PS tools like PSKill. PSExec is a remote shell utility like SSH (though not at all secure for crossing the Internet). You do need to be in the administrators  group on  the remote PC, either by virtual of your domain membership and roles, or defined locally. you do not need more access than local admin to kill processes. It is possible to connect to a system as the SYSTEM account with `psexec -s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches you can take to remote kill processes from a CLI:

---

### Powershell

Assuming you have an account with the requisite permissions, and have configured Powershell for remote use (not covered in this answer, but [here's a free e-book from Don Jones](http://powershell.org/wp/2012/08/06/ebook-secrets-of-powershell-remoting/) covering how to get set up,) you can use one of several Cmdlets to remotely kill processes.

#### Stop-Process via Invoke-Command

You should be able to use `Stop-Process` along with an `Invoke-Command` (or by opening a more permanent remote session).

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputer -ScriptBlock {Stop-Process processname}
```

This would be my preference, but requires some configuration in advance, so is not ideal in every situation.

---

### Built-in Solutions

#### Taskkill.exe

[Taskkill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb491009.aspx) is provided on recent Windows machines, and can be used remotely with the `/s` parameter.

Example:

```
taskkill /s remotecomputer /pid processID
```

---

### Sysinternals Tools

You can also use either of **PSKill** or **PSExec** (available at [live.sysinternals.com](http://live.sysinternals.com)) to terminate processes.

#### PSKill

Similar to Taskkill, but not provided on Windows machines by default.

Example:

```
pskill \\remotecomputer <process ID | name>
```

#### PSExec

Using PSExec, on the other hand, you can run any command you would normally use to manage processes locally.

Example:

```
psexec \\remotecomputer taskkill /pid processID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command from cmd or the start menu:

```
taskkill /f /im name.exe
```

This also has a `/S` parameter to allow you to set the system to connect to.  So you will be able to:

```
taskkill /s remoteserver /f /im name.exe
```

To find name.exe,

```
tasklist
```

will give you a chart with all the processes, the names, the executable (name.exe) and the PID [process ID].